# Add custom endpoint to gateway

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have legacy application which I need to make work with the new jhipster microservices app. The code in the legacy app cannot be modified and all the rest calls start with "/d". By default jhipster has only one entrypoint for rest calls which is "/api".

I created a new controller ( I even tried modifying existing ones by remapping to /d) and added my endpoint "/d" to SecurityConfiguration `.antMatchers("/d/**").authenticated()` and even added on the WebConfigurer `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/d/**", config);` even though I don't think this helps.

When I try to access my endpoint via postman with the authentication set, I get

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /d</pre>
</body>
```

Which is peculiar because if I try to access a non existing endpoint that start with /api, I get the following error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-02-26T09:28:04.065+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "Not Found",
"path": "/api/d"
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
I found out that in my application-dev.yml I had server.port = 8080 and I was making the requests on a different port: 9000, which was the port on which I was accessing the gateway homepage. At the same time all my requests that I was making on localhost:9000/api were working, but localhost:9000/d, did not, while on 8080 they both work. Can anyone explain what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of pain and suffering a front end colleague enlightened me. I had to add my path to the devServer.proxy.context variable inside webpack.dev.js.